# Configure Sonar to see Integration Tests (v6.2)

Tags: maven, sonarqube, integration-testing, code-coverage

**How to visualize Integration Tests in Sonar ?**

Currently I only see :

- the global coverage (UT + IT)
- the number of UT

[image]

I read somewhere we had to configure a widget in the GUI : I didn't see any option which could do that.

**Documentation states :**

> If coverage by unit tests is not computed with JaCoCo, overall
>   coverage = integration test coverage.

But in my case I see that the coverage is changing when I change my UTs (or ITs). Moreover I see jacoco reports in the targets :

- jacoco.exec
- jacoco-it.exec

I finaly tryed the official Sonar samples : it is the same ! I didn't find any sample with a clear separation between :

- Unit test coverage
- Integration test coverage
- Overall test coverage

And sorry but Sonar documentation and samples have to be improved...

**Context :** sonar6.2, java8, spring boot, modular project, maven, surefire & failsafe

Comment: What version of SonarQube are you using? Also, feel free to propose specific enhancements to the documentation and PRs to the examples.

Comment: I am using V6.2. I would be glad to propose a boilerplate maven project with Spring Boot and sonar, but I first need to do it :) I think [examples here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/maven) could be improved. As [theses ones](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-maven).

Comment: I believe your question regarding `jacoco.exec` and `jacoco-it.exec` have been answered elsewhere. Perhaps you would [edit] your question to remove that portion & to add "SonarQube 6.2" to your context?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting in SonarQube 6.2, all test results are merged into simply "coverage". This was done on the theory that by and large, most people don't care *how* their code is covered, only *that* it is covered.

With this change, some math inconsistencies w/r/t how Overall Coverage was calculated from unit tests versus integration tests were eliminated, and additionally the ability to feed many different coverage reports was added. (Some people have unit, integration, smoke, ... tests).

Regarding

> I read somewhere we had to configure a widget in the GUI : I didn't see any option which could do that.

In 6.2 dashboards were dropped, so there are no widgets to be configured. Coverage is shown automatically on the project home page.

Comment: Thanks, could you please provide some links about this change (IT coverage removed) and about "the ability to feed many different coverage reports" ?
I checked [v6.2 release](https://jira.sonarsource.com/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10930&version=13327) but see nothing.

Comment: Doing a browser search of "coverage" highlights a few things, including [SONAR-8281 - Change coverage API to accept unlimited reports and merge them](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8281), and [SONAR-8326 - Drop all code related to IT/overall coverage on web side](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8326). There's also the [Consolidated Coverage](https://blog.sonarsource.com/sonarqube-6-2-in-screenshots/) section of the release post on the blog.

Comment: G. Ann, It seems somewhat odd/misleading to have a "Coverage" number that is a combination of unit, integration, etc. sitting next to a count of, and link to, just the Unit Tests. Would it be possible to get that changed to just "Tests", and link to everything provided by sonar.tests?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, In your post, in the _Consolitated coverage_ section, we see the number of the unit tests (420). Is it only the number of the unit tests or the number for all types of test? If so, how can we have the number of unit tests + instrumented tests? In my gradle file, I use the "sonar.junit.reportsPath" property but I can provide one path only, either the path to the unit test report or the path to the instrumented test report... not several paths...

Comment: The obtuse answer is that the interface shows what you feed it. If you combine numbers before analysis, then it will be all tests. The long answer is that we don't see the value in execution reports & made no attempt to extend / modify / update the behavior in this regard when the work my answer describes was done.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam "interface shows what you feed it." Is there any way currently to feed 2 reports and have them separately shown for same project? Or the only option is to have 2 projects 1 for Unit and 2nd for IT (and 3rd for total)?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Could you please check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514090/sonarqube-how-can-one-turn-off-sonar-analyser-but-still-get-coverage-report

Answer (score 0):

Merging unit testing coverage and integration testing coverage numbers is not a good idea.

Modern unit tests that mock out all dependencies and environmental factors and have been proven to run on a developers local machine cannot by definition fail in a continuous integration environment. This makes them next to useless to run in a CI environment. Therefore, 100% unit test coverage but 0% integration test coverage means no meaningful testing is actually happening in the CI build.

Comment: What makes you think that unit tests "cannot fail"? Of course they can: no developer is forced to run them locally before commiting, and a local system can differ from the production system in many aspects

Comment: This is not an attempt to answer the question