# Number of unit tests in SonarQube

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a multi modules maven project (this should not be relevant), configured with the `jacoco-maven-plugin`. From what I understand, the jacoco plugin is responsible to analyze the code by generating binary `jacoco*.exec` file. It's also responsible to produce reports (jacoco.xml) that will be imported by Sonar via `sonar-maven-plugin`.

The `jacoco-maven-plugin` is configured like that. The `prepare-agent` and `prepare-agent-integration` goals setup the jacoco agent for both unit and integration tests. Then the `merge` goal creates a single `jacoco.exec` file to have unit and integration tests in a single `.exec` file. In the `verify` phase, the `report` goal create the `jacoco.xml` based on the merged `jacoco.exec` file.

In SonarQube, the coverage is working but the number of unit tests seems not to include integration tests. With this setup I have 80+% coverage and 54 unit tests. If I remove the `prepare-agent` goal, the coverage is down to 20% but still 54 unit tests whereas there are 5 integration tests. So it means that the coverage for integration tests is working but the number of unit tests is not working.

My understanding is that the number of unit tests in SonarQube is the number of unit and integration tests. There is no dedicated counter for integration tests.

So how is the number of unit tests calculated by SonarQube? by parsing surefire report? The class name for the integration test is MyResourceIT.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.5</version>
</plugin>
<executions>
 <execution> 
  <goals>
   <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
   <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
  </configuration>
 </execution>
 <execution> 
  <id>pre-integration-prepare</id>
  <goals>
   <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
 <execution> 
  <id>report</id>
  <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>merge</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
   <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
     <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
     <includes>
      <include>*.exec</include>
     </includes>
    </fileSet>
   </fileSets>
  </configuration>
 </execution>
 <execution> 
  <id>merged-report-generation</id>
  <phase>verify</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>report</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
</executions>
```

Source: https://medium.com/@vareshtapadia/unit-and-integration-test-coverage-report-to-sonarqube-ca0a9a492675

Comment: I followed the info found at https://natritmeyer.com/howto/reporting-aggregated-unit-and-integration-test-coverage-with-jacoco/ and came up with the same results as you. I'm certainly curious to know the answer to your question as I cannot find anything that can confirm or deny your suspicions other than what's shown at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785791/configure-sonar-to-see-integration-tests-v6-2?rq=1.